# Почему говорят, что интерфейс описывает поведение объекта?

Tags: ооп, интерфейс

Если вдуматься, интерфейс никак не описывает поведение, он описывает контракт и способ взаимодействия, а поведение описывается в реализации. Но я постоянно слышу, что люди говорят, что интерфейс описывает поведение. Получается, так говорить ошибочно?

Comment: Ну, как бы набор методов объекта - это как-раз "поведение" объекта, то, что он умеет и чем мы можем управлять. Например, если интерфейс описывает методы `move` и `shoot`, значит объект умеет двигаться и стрелять. В этом смысле. А так в общем-то это вопрос трактовки терминов, хочешь так, а хочешь эдак.

Comment: @CrazyElf согласен с ТС, то что объект можно попросить *подвинуться или пострелять*, никак не гарантирует нам того, что объект ***будет** двигаться или стрелять* (например, у него банально нету ножек и ружья).

Comment: Мы неправильно воспринимаем move и shoot. Move и shoot у каждого объекта будет реакцией на просьбу подвигаться и пострелять (в реальности там вообще может выпасть исключение и объект не станет ничего делать), в интерфейсе мы только определяем, что объект, реализующий данный интерфейс **будет иметь** свое поведение (реакцию) на запрос пострелять и подвигаться, но никак это поведение не определяем. Определяет его реализация

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста в вопросе, **а кто так говорит и где?** Потому что я пока в основном вижу, что говорится "interface describes a set of method signatures / object properties"

Comment: @Kromster, вы прямо сейчас можете спросить любого знакомого разработчика, описывает ли интерфейс поведение объекта и почти со стопроцентной вероятностью получите утвердительный ответ

Comment: Не, ну это почти как ОБС и "проблема цитат в Интернете .." - не считается. Почему условный Вася считает считает что Земля плоская - спрашивать надо у него.

Comment: @Kromster, ну вы даже сами посмотрите. У вопроса 2 ответа и один про то что интерфейс описывает поведение

Comment: Не, ну это и правда тогда обсуждение того, что кто-то где-то что-то сказал, а кто, где и что именно - неизвестно. Контракт - более строгое понятие, другое дело, что если начинающий программист будет читать книжку, где будет написано, что "интерфейс - это контракт", он ничего не поймёт. Скорее всего фраза про поведение взята из какой-то книжки для начинающих программистов. Просто чтобы им было чуть понятнее.

Comment: Это проблема "наводящих" вопросов - вы сформулировали утверждение похожее на правду, указали что так считает вымышленное большинство и просите его опровергнуть. (и интерпретации, имхо только 1 ответ подтверждает ваш тезис и у него уже 2 минуса).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь проблема определений.

Что называть поведением? Если мы говорим про поведение чисто в контексте взаимодействия с другими объектами, то здесь под поведением мы понимаем то, какие методы объект предоставляет, в каком формате через эти методы он принимает запросы, и в каком формате возвращает ответы.

С этой точки зрения - да, интерфейс определяет поведение.

Но если рассматривать более широкий контекст, то, конечно, есть много аспектов, которые можно назвать поведением, но которые не описываются интерфейсом.

Comment: Мне кажется, нужно ориентироваться на примеры из реальной жизни. В реальной жизни поведением мы называем реакцию на действие, а не наличие этой реакции

Answer (score -2):

Именно интерфейс описывает поведение. Ведь именно в интерфейсе будут определены методы например **есть** или **говорить**. А вот говорить на английском или испанском, есть курицу или торт - это уже детали. **Есть** и **говорить** - это и есть описание поведения, а есть курицу - это фактическая реализация поведения. Такие детали реализации как курица, или торт - хранятся в реализируюем классе. А само поведение в интерфейсе. И это концептуально правильно. Потому что, описав поведение в интерфейсе, а не реализующем классе у вас станут возможным полиморфизм, абстракция и повторное использование кода.

Comment: В реальной жизни поведением мы называем реакцию на что-то. Например, "Как ведет себя твоя собака, когда ты приходишь домой?" - мы уточняем поведение, зная, что у нее есть какая-то реакция на возвращение хозяина домой. То есть запрашиваем поведение в реализации. Интерфейс абстрактной собаки мы знаем, т.е. мы знаем (предполагаем), что у нее есть какое-то поведение, потому что оно есть у всех собак (все собаки реализуют интерфейс), но вот само поведение - у каждой свое, это принадлежность к конкретному объекту